# Source column in perf report shows some [unknown]

Tags: gcc, kernel, perf

For a simple C code like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  FILE *pf;
  while (i++ <= 1000000) {
    if ( i%2 == 0 ) {
      pf = fopen( "myfile.txt", "a" );
      fprintf( pf, "%d\n", i );
      fclose( pf );
    } else {
      printf("%d ", i);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I used the following commands to build the binary

```
$ gcc -c test.c 
$ gcc -o test -Wl,--emit-relocs \ 
      -Wl,--rpath=/opt/glibc-2.23-install \
      -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/opt/glibc-2.23-install/lib/ld-2.23.so \
      test.o
```

Then I ran the following two `perf` commands to record and report.

```
$ perf record -e cycles:u -j any,u -a -o perf.data.user -- test
$ perf report -i perf.data.user
```

Part of the output is shown below:

```
# Overhead  Command  Source Shared Object  Source Symbol                              Target Symbol                              Basic Block Cycles
# ........  .......  ....................  .........................................  .........................................  ..................
#
     7.69%  perf     libc-2.23.so          [.] __GI_____strtoll_l_internal            [.] __GI_____strtoll_l_internal            -
     5.13%  perf     perf                  [.] perf_evsel__enable                     [.] perf_evsel__enable                     -
     4.49%  perf     perf                  [.] perf_mmap__push                        [.] perf_mmap__push                        -
     4.49%  test     libc-2.23.so          [.] _int_malloc                            [.] _int_malloc                            -
     3.85%  perf     perf                  [.] __perf_mmap__read_init                 [.] __perf_mmap__read_init                 -
     3.85%  perf     ld-2.23.so            [.] strcmp                                 [.] strcmp                                 -
     3.85%  test     ld-2.23.so            [.] _dl_map_object_deps                    [.] _dl_map_object_deps                    -
     3.21%  perf     perf                  [.] record__mmap_read_evlist.constprop.27  [.] record__mmap_read_evlist.constprop.27  -
     2.56%  perf     [unknown]             [.] 0xffffffffb2c00ae7                     [.] __read_nocancel                        -
     2.56%  perf     perf                  [.] record__mmap_read_evlist.constprop.27  [.] perf_mmap__push                        -
     2.56%  perf     perf                  [.] perf_mmap__push                        [.] record__mmap_read_evlist.constprop.27  -
     2.56%  test     libc-2.23.so          [.] malloc                                 [.] malloc                                 -
     1.92%  perf     [unknown]             [.] 0xffffffffb2c00ae7                     [.] perf_mmap__push                        -
     1.92%  perf     perf                  [.] cmd_record                             [.] cmd_record                             -
....
```

I would like to know what is `[unknown]` in the source column? and why there is no `main` in the report? Although I showed part of the output, in fact there is no main in the report file.

Comment: Those `0xff...` high addresses might be the VDSO, or they might be inside the kernel itself.  Actually that might not be high enough to be the `[vsyscall]` region the kernel maps into user-space; check `tail /proc/self/maps` to see what address is typical on your system.

Comment: Yes. That is VDSO.